# Node: Check a Firebase db and execute a function when an objects time matches the current time

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cron

**Background**

I have a Node and React based application. I'm using Firebase for my storage and database. In my application users can fill out a form where they upload an image and select a time for the image to be added to their website. I save each image update as an object in my Firebase database like so. Images are arranged in order of ascending update time.

```
user-name: {
   images: [
     {
        src: 'image-src-url',
        updateTime: 1503953587727
     }
     {
        src: 'image-src-url',
        updateTime: 1503958424838
     }
   ]
}
```

**Scale**

My applications db could potentially get very large with a lot of users and images. I'd like to ensure scalability.

**Issue**

How do I check when a specific image objects time has been met then execute a function? (I do not need assistance on the actual function that is being run just the checking of the db for a specific time.)

**Attempts**

I've thought about doing a cron job using [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) that checks the entire database every 60s (users can only specify the minute the image will update, not the seconds.) Then if it finds a matching updateTime and executes my function. My concern is at a large scale that cron job will take a while to search the db and potentially miss a time.

I've also thought about when the user schedules a new update then dynamically create a specific cron job for that time. I'm unsure how to accomplish this.

Any other methods that may work? Are my concerns about node-cron not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches I can think of:

1. Keep track of the last timestamp you processed
2. Keep the "things to process" in a queue

#### Keep track of the last timestamp you processed

When you process items, you use the current timestamp as the cut-off point for your query. Something like:

```
var now = Date.now();
var query = ref.orderByChild("updateTime").endAt(now)
```

Now make sure to store this `now` somewhere (i.e. in your database) so that you can re-use it next time to retrieve the next batch of items:

```
var previous = ... previous value of now
var now = Date.now();
var query = ref.orderByChild("updateTime").startAt(previous).endAt(now);
```

With this you're only processing a single slice at a time. The only tricky bit is that somebody might insert a new node with an `updateTime` that you've already processed. If this is a concern for your use-case, you can prevent them from doing so with a validation rule on `updateTime`:

```
".validate": "newData.val() >= root.child('lastProcessed').val()"
```

As you add more items to the database, you will indeed be querying more items. So there is a scalability limit to this approach, but this approach should work well for anything up to a few hundreds of thousands of nodes (I haven't tested in a while so ymmv).

For a few previous questions on list size:

- [Firebase Performance: How many children per node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712833/firebase-performance-how-many-children-per-node)
- [Firebase Scalability Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746094/firebase-scalability-limit)
- [How many records / rows / nodes is alot in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857905/how-many-records-rows-nodes-is-alot-in-firebase)

#### Keep the "things to process" in a queue

An alternative approach is to keep a queue of items that still need to be processed. So the clients add the items that they want processed to the queue with an `updateTime` of when they want to processed. And your server picks the items from the queue, performs the necessary updates,  and **removes the item from the queue**:

```
var now = Date.now();
var query = ref.orderByChild("updateTime").endAt(now)
query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

    // TODO: process the child node

    // remove the child node from the queue
    child.ref.remove();
  });
})
```

The difference with the earlier approach is that a queue's stable state is going to be empty (or at least quite small), so your queries will run against a much smaller list. That's also why you won't need to keep track of the last timestamp you processed: any item in the queue up to now is eligible for processing.

Comment: Frank great ideas here. I'm leaning towards the second option. Do you think the queue should be separate from my regular database list. I.E Currently I do have a 'queue' but its stored under each individuals user ID. Are you suggesting I also add the images to a new node named 'queue'? Or can I keep my structure and do the same queries you are suggesting?

Comment: Option 2 is indeed a separate node for the queue, where you delete the items after you've processed them,

Comment: Option #2 is the option I'm going with! It makes my db writes a bit more complicated but is helpful for these quick reads.

Comment: Frank - Given that I'm a new app and havn't launched yet, I'm considering migrating my db to Cloud Firestore. A big factor in that decision is the same ability to quickly query and process images whose update time has been met. Given my question a few months ago, do you recommend I do the migration? Would your approach #2 translate to having a separate collection for the queue?

Comment: While Cloud Firestore offers better scalability and significantly simplifies querying over multiple properties, I don't think it offers anything significantly different for this scenario. You'd indeed make a separate collection for the queue.